# Wordpress generates weird permalinks

Tags: php, permalinks, google

I have a problem with weird permalinks generated by wordpress

```
https://example.com/page/19/
https://example.com/page/19/?cat=-1
https://example.com/?cat=-1
```

How I can fix it and disable generating those urls?

Comment: How do you have your permalinks configured? **Settings > Permalinks**

Comment: only - /%postname%/

Comment: have a check with https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/ what does create those url, i think this comes from your thème or a plugin, not from wordpress